# socket.py not creating listener on server

Tags: sockets, tcp, configuration, ufw

I set variables host and port instead of setting the 'address' variable tuple in socket.py. I was unable to get 'address' as a tuple to work. I do not believe this is the issue, but I thought I should state this up front.

FYI, my goal is an integrations project, and I believe I isolated socket.py as the problematic code. socket.py is not creating a listener on the remote server. I run the python script on my client, and my server address is 192.168.1.130 port 7879.

I *think* socket.py is the problem, because I do not receive the expected print statements back through the console that socket.py is attempting to create a socket. In addition, I can RDC to the server, disable ufw (yes I know this is a bad idea), create a tcp listener, push data through the client socket to the server socket, and verify this with netcat.

Am I mistaken that I should be able to parameterize socket.py with nothing more than a host and port and be able to create a socket connection? I am happy to provide more detail from logs, but I thought I should start with a very high level overview.

Comment: Can you post the actual code of `socket.py`?

Comment: Sure. The socket.py code is part of a standard github pull, my only mod was to set the host and port variable. The code is too long to post. You can see it here. http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r27a4/Lib/socket.py

Comment: I am adding the link to the code that is calling sockey.py. https://github.com/mtconnect/ros_bridge/blob/master/mtconnect/mtconnect_ros_bridge/scripts/src/mtconnect_adapter.py

Comment: Ah, by `socket.py` you mean python's socket module from the standard library, not something you wrote yourself. Ok. You should post an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you were trying to achieve using the socket module. While it's not out of question that the Python Standard Library has a bug, I would look at your own code first.

Comment: Thanks margold, I will post to MCVE. I have been working on this for a few months during free time and finally reached the point where I thought I ought ask LOL. I appreciate the response.

Comment: The I am trying to achieve is wiring the code found here: https://github.com/mtconnect/ros_bridge/tree/master/mtconnect/mtconnect_ros_bridge/scripts/src which enables data communication from a CNC machine through client/server sockets. Please read my initial post for the problem as I have currently isolated it.

Comment: From the set of four python modules in the link above, data_item will work ONLY if you have LinuxCNC installed. However, data_item is working properly in my environment, and the code fails before any call to the module is reached. You should be able to parameterize a value for data_item as needed

Comment: I start with mtconnect_adapter.py. If I am correct, all I need do is set the 'address' variable ('192.168.1.130' , 7879) , and the calls to socket.py, threading.py, socketserver.py made from mtconnect_adapter.py should return messages through the console like "Server started, waiting for connections on 192.168.1.130". This is not the case. The code is not creating a socket on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: More investigation needed. I think socket.py does not create the remote connection with socket(),bind(),listen() statements; instead simply looks for a listener on the remote server with a connect() statement. This is entirely my misunderstanding given I did not dive into the details of the socket.py code. I figured this out because the service running on the remote server creates the listener, but the service itself on the remote server is what is not properly starting.